# Set values in a page according to data-values in a button

Tags: html, jquery, button, events

I have the following statements on a page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="proc" id="proc" value="">
<img src="/images/test" class="img-fluid" id="procselect" alt="">
```

Depending on what button is clicked the values val in the hidden field and src in the image should be populated from the data fields

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary proccard" data-cardid="proc01" data-front="/images/test2.png">Select</button>   
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary proccard" data-cardid="proc02" data-front="/images/test3.png">Select</button>
```

I am using the following javascript:

```
$('#ProcModal').on('click', '.proccard', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var cardid = button.data('cardid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var front = button.data('front') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    body.find('#procselect').attr('src', front)
    body.find('form #proc').val(cardid)
    $('ProcModal').modal('hide')
})

When a button is clicked nothing happens and I see the following error in the console:

selectproc.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (selectproc.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Is jQuery not able to find the button according to the class? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since you haven't uploaded working modal, I have made is work, just change according to your need. You need to use `$("body")` instead of `body`

```js
$(".proccard").click(function() {
  var button = $(this);
  var cardid = button.data('cardid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var front = button.data('front') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  $("body").find('#procselect').attr('src', front)
  $("body").find('#proc').val(cardid)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="proc" id="proc" value="" readonly> <!-- just to show value is changing -->
<img src="/images/test" class="img-fluid" id="procselect" alt="hello">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary proccard" data-cardid="proc01" data-front="/images/test2.png">Select</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary proccard" data-cardid="proc02" data-front="/images/test3.png">Select</button>
```

Comment: Thank you!! That did the trick!! It is working perfectly now!!